# Sequences in topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

How can we prove that the sequence {1/n} is convergent in $\mathbf R$ with usual and indiscrete topology but not with discrete topology?

Comment: What is the distance between $\frac{1}{n}$ and $0$ in the discrete topology?

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to read question clearly in my android. In question there is use of symbol $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Usual topology**

For $\epsilon >0$ we have $0<1/N < \epsilon$ as soon as $N \ge 1/\epsilon$.

**Indiscrete topology**

The only open sets are $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb R$. And for all $n \in \mathbb N$... we have $x_n \in \mathbb R$!

**Discrete topology**

Suppose that $\{x_n\}$ converges to $l$, as $\{l\}$ is an open subspace of $\mathbb R$ for the discrete topology we would need to find $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $x_n \in \{l\}$ for all $n \ge N$. And this not possible.